# awscli s3 sync wildcards

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, synchronization, wildcard, aws-cli

I'm trying to sync all files in a directory that start with "model.ckpt" to an S3 bucket path, by trying this:

`aws s3 sync ./model.ckpt* $S3_CKPT_PATH`

But I'm getting the error:

`Unknown options: ./model.ckpt-0.meta,<my S3_CKPT_PATH path>`

However, `aws s3 sync . $S3_CKPT_PATH` works, but gives me a lot of additional files I don't want.

Anybody know how I can do this?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

When using `aws s3 sync`, all files in a folder are included.

If you wish to specify wildcards, you will need to [Use Exclude and Include Filters](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/index.html#use-of-exclude-and-include-filters).

For example:

```
aws s3 sync mydir s3://bucket/folder/ --exclude "*" --include "model.ckpt*"
```